# How to get existing payment method from braintree in android?

Tags: android, python, http, payment, braintree

I have an android client which makes a call to a flask python server like so:

```
public void getCustomerPaymentMethods() {
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme("http")
            .authority("www.server.appspot.com")
            .appendPath("get_customer_payment_methods")
            .appendPath(mCustomerId);

    String url = builder.build().toString();

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(url, new BaseJsonHttpResponseHandler<List<>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String rawJsonResponse, List<> response) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, String rawJsonData, List<> errorResponse) {
            // Display UI for no payment methods
            mNoPaymentMethodImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mAddPaymentMethodButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected List<> parseResponse(String rawJsonData, boolean isFailure) throws Throwable {
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

This is the server side code mapped to the url provided:

```
@app.route('/get_customer_payment_methods/<cutomerId>')
def get_customer_payment_methods(customerId):
    result = braintree.Customer.find(customerId)
    return result.payment_methods
```

What object do I have to save the response from the python server in on the client side?

Comment: Is flask returning json, or a string representation of this Braintree object?

Comment: The braintree docs say that the flask is returning a list of payment methods for a specific customer. @cricket_007

Comment: Can you please show the response in your question when you simply access that server url from a browser? Be sure to remove any sensitive information when you do

Comment: I'm not too sure, but you may want to look at this https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-Android-Async-Http-Client#sending-a-json-request